# What is the "About the Author" blurb in Shadows of the Empire supposed to say?

Tags: star-wars, authors

In my (2012 kindle) copy of the 1996 novel *Star Wars:  Shadows of the Empire*, the brief blurb about science fiction author Steve Perry seems to have at least two misprints:

[image]

> ABOUT THE AUTHOR
>   Steve Perry wrote for ***Batman: Ther Wars: Shadows of the Empire*,** and wrote the bestselling novelization **of the blockbuster Animated Series** during its first Emmy Award-winning season, authored the New York Times bestsellers *Star Wars: Death Star* (with Michael Reaves) **and Stauster movie *Men in Black*.** Perry has sold dozens of stories to magazines and anthologies, and has published a considerable number of novels, animated teleplays, nonfiction articles, reviews, and essays. He is currently the science fiction, fantasy, and horror book reviewer for *The Oregonian*.
>   (Italics in the original;  bold shows the problematic lines)

What is this blurb *supposed* to say?

Comment: You have a copy of a novel from 19916??!

Comment: Well, this is an interesting new kind of question!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found a similar version of that "About the Author" quote [here](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/indiana-jones-and-the-army-of-the-dead-steve-perry/1101057791?ean=9780345506986), which reads as follows:

> Steve Perry wrote for Batman: Ther Wars: Shadows of the Empire, and wrote the bestselling novelization of the blockb Animated Series during its first Emmy Award-winning season, authored the New York Times bestsellers Star Wars: Death Star (with Michael Reaves) and Stauster movie Men in Black. Perry has sold dozens of stories to magazines and anthologies, and has published a considerable number of novels, animated teleplays, nonfiction articles, reviews, and essays. He is currently the science fiction, fantasy, and horror book reviewer for The Oregonian.

According to his [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Perry_(author)#Television) page, he wrote for Batman: The Animated Series, which according to its [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103359/awards) page won an Emmy in 1993. He also wrote the novelisation for Men in Black in 1998. My best guess is that it's supposed to read something like this (the first sentence just got a bit muddled up):

> Steve Perry wrote for Batman: The Animated Series during its first Emmy Award-winning season, authored the New York Times bestsellers Star Wars: Death Star (with Michael Reaves) and Star Wars: Shadows of the Empire, and wrote the bestselling novelization of the blockbuster movie Men in Black. Perry has sold dozens of stories to magazines and anthologies, and has published a considerable number of novels, animated teleplays, nonfiction articles, reviews, and essays. He is currently the science fiction, fantasy, and horror book reviewer for The Oregonian.

That's mostly just re-ordering the information. The word "Stauster" (for which I could find no relevant information) appears to be the "Sta" that should go along with "r Wars: Shadows of the Empire", and the "uster" goes with the "blockb" that's before "Animated Series" in the mangled version.

Comment: Brilliant job.  I knew "Stauster" wasn't a real word, and I knew "Sta" was missing from "Star Wars:  Shadows of the Empire", but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I was curious what the original mixup was, and it turns out there's only one section that's been moved: "r Wars: Shadows of the Empire, and wrote the bestselling novelization of the blockb". Probably an accidental drag-and-drop in a word processor.